# file_get_contents error in php with codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am doing this tutorial but with a diferent xml http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/03/parsing-xml-file-using-codeigniters-simplexml-library/, but I keep getting the same error: 
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: myxml
Filename: controllers/welcome.php
Line Number: 45**

this my mi code: I put the xml file in the directory C:\Users\beto\Documents\xml\myxml.xml, but I think I am wrong can you help me, or tell me how to fix it?

```
function _getXML($fname)
  {

      $filename = $fname.’.xml’;
      $xmlfile=“C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml”.$filename;
      **$xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);**ERROR

      $this->load->library(‘simplexml’);
      $xmlData = $this->simplexml->xml_parse($xmlRaw);

      foreach($xmlData[‘Emisor’] as $row)
      {

    $result .= ‘<tr>’;
    $result .= ‘<td>’.$row[‘id’].’</td>’;
    $result .= ‘<td>’.$row[‘name’].’</td>’;
    $result .= ‘<td>’.$row[‘category’].’</td>’;
    $result .= ‘<td>$ ‘.$row[‘price’].’</td>’;
    $result .= ‘</tr>’;

      }
        return $result;
  }
```

Comment: You should show controllers/welcome.php and line 45 there

Comment: is the line that says  **$xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);**ERROR

Comment: Your error message does not match your source code, the notice talks about `$myxml` but there is no `$mysql` in the source posted.

Comment: I changed to $xmlfile="“C:\Users\beto\Documents\xml\".$filename;, but now the error says is in foreach($xmlData[‘Emisor’] as $row), I think its a big mistake is in the first 5 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `\` is missing, replace like:

```
$xmlfile="C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml\\".$filename;
```

Comment: i would jsut use `realpath('/Users/beto/Documents/xml/'.$filename);` and forget about all the escaping... `realpath` should translate to a windows system path.

Comment: I change in this way: 
                $xmlfile="“C:\Users\beto\Documents\xml\".$filename; but now the error is in foreach($xmlData['Emisor'] as $row) what??, and the name of my xml is myxml

Comment: @GeorgeBecj bad xml, I suppose?

Comment: @prodigitalson you mean instead of $xmlfile="“C:\Users\beto\Documents\xml\".$filename; this $realpath('/Users/beto/Documents/xml/'.$filename); or how?

Comment: You still need to use the drive letter `realpath('C:/Users/beto/Documents/xml/'.$filename);` Also that function will return `false` if the file does not exist so you should check for that.